# How to fit long running equation in one line

Tags: align, amsmath

I want this equation to be in one single line or any more way to write it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{mathbbol}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{braket}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \left(1-\iota\frac{J_x\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_x^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)\left(1-\iota\frac{J_y\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_y^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)-\left(1-\iota\frac{J_y\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_y^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)\left(1-\iota\frac{J_x\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_x^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)
    \end{equation*}
    \end{documen}
```

Comment: Please clarify what `\iota` represents. E.g., is it the imaginary unit, viz., `\sqrt{-1}`?

Comment: @Mico yes it is the imaginary number that we study in high school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{mathbbol}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{braket}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
&    \left(1-\iota\frac{J_x\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_x^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)\left(1-\iota\frac{J_y\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_y^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)\\
&\quad-\left(1-\iota\frac{J_y\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_y^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)\left(1-\iota\frac{J_x\epsilon}{\hbar}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2!}\frac{J_x^2}{\hbar^2}+\ldots\right)
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```